# An example of a non unitary isometry on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I would like to see one or preferrably two isometries on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ which are non surjective (equivalently non unitaries)?

Thanks in advance.

Math.

Comment: Transfer the unilateral (right) shift on $\ell^2$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, for example.

Comment: some more details are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give you uncountably many non-unitary isometries.  For $T>0$, define $U_T:L^2(\mathbb R)\to L^2(\mathbb R)$ by 
\begin{align*}
(U_Tf)(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
f(t-T) &:& t\in[T,\infty),\\
0 &:& t\in[0,T),\\
f(t)&:&t\in(-\infty,0).
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

That is 
$$U_Tf (x) = \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,0)}(x)f(x) + f(x-T)\mathbb{1}_{[T,\infty)}(x)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Aweygan. But I would like one "in one piece" if this is possible.

Comment: Please define what you mean.

Comment: I mean just one expression for $t$ fully in $\mathbb{R}$ not in three parts as is your interesting example.

Comment: @Math: It is not difficult to put things in one line. Try to do it yourself. The pint being is that the operator $U_T$ is the summer of two operators: the first $S$ is multiplication by $\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,0)}$ as in $Sf=\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,0)}f$, and the second $W$ is the composition of multiplication by $\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}$ with the translation (by T units) to the right as in $Wf =\tau_T(\mathbb{1}_{([0,\infty)}f)$, where $\tau_Tg=g(\cdot-T)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oliver Diaz.